# Invalid access to memory location with ReadFile

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I have a file, **C:\demo\Demo.txt**, that has a simple "**Hello, world**" on it. I want to pass the path as argument to my app, open it with `CreateFile`, read it with `ReadFile` and show that line out on console. However, I am receiving an error code `998`:

> Invalid access to memory location.

This is my code:

```
int wmain(int argc, WCHAR **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"\nWrong arguments. \n");
        return 1;
    }

    // CreateFile function variables
    HANDLE hSourceFile;
    LPCWSTR fileName = (LPCWSTR)argv[1];
    DWORD desiredAccess = FILE_GENERIC_READ;
    DWORD shareMode = FILE_SHARE_READ;
    DWORD creationDisposition = OPEN_EXISTING;
    DWORD flagsAndAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Opening file for reading data
    hSourceFile = CreateFileW(
        fileName,
        desiredAccess,
        shareMode,
        NULL,
        creationDisposition,
        flagsAndAttributes,
        NULL);

    if (hSourceFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        wprintf(L"\nThe source file, %s, is open. \n", fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Error code: %u\n", GetLastError());
    }

    // ReadFile function variables
    LPVOID dataRead=NULL;
    DWORD bytesToRead = 100;
    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Reading data from file
    if (!ReadFile(
        hSourceFile,
        dataRead,
        bytesToRead,
        &bytesWritten,
        NULL))
    {
        wprintf(L"Error code: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;

    }

    wprintf(L"%s. \n", (LPWSTR)dataRead);   


    CloseHandle(hSourceFile);

    return 0;
}
```

First time I use `ReadFile`, so no idea what I am doing wrong.

Can you help me?

Comment: `LPVOID dataRead=NULL;` -> `char dataRead[100];`. `ReadFile` wants a pointer to valid memory.

Comment: Other unrelated problems: if `hSourceFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` you print the error code, but then you proceed to `ReadFile` anyway which is pointless. And you print the content of the `dataRead` buffer without ensuring there is a NUL terminator. And if the file you've read is not encoded in DBCS (double byte character string), you will print garbage.

Comment: Were you expecting `ReadFile` to change the value of `dataRead`? If it was going to change the value stored in `dataRead`, wouldn't it have taken a pointer to `dataRead` rather than its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReadFile` wants a pointer to a buffer into which it can write the data.  You are passing NULL, so you get the error you see.

I would change the code to

```
    // ReadFile function variables
    static const DWORD bytesToRead = 100;
    unsigned char dataRead[bytesToRead];
    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Reading data from file
    if (!ReadFile(
        hSourceFile,
        dataRead,
        bytesToRead,
        &bytesWritten,
        NULL))
    {
        wprintf(L"Error code: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
```

The next problem you have, is that you are casting your pointer to `LPWSTR`, that is a pointer to a *null-terminated* wide string.  Does your file contain that null termination? or do you need to add it yourself? Assuming the file *doesn't* contain the termination, you probably want:

```
    // ReadFile function variables
    static const DWORD bufferSize = 50;
    WCHAR buffer[bufferSize+1];  // Leave room for null.
    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Reading data from file
    if (!ReadFile(
        hSourceFile,
        buffer,
        bufferSize*sizeof(WCHAR),
        &bytesWritten,
        NULL))
    {
        wprintf(L"Error code: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    buffer[bytesWritten/sizeof(WCHAR)] = 0; // Null terminate.
    wprintf(L"%s. \n", buffer);  // Look ma!  No cast needed.
```

Comment: Tried that, but It is printing **??????????**. I was trying to cast from LPVOID to LPWSTR so I could print it.

Answer (score 1):

You must allocate a memory buffer where you want to place read bytes to. Now you pointer `dataRead` points to `nullptr`, in other words nowhere, but you pass the size 100, that states your pointer refers to 100 byte allocated buffer, it is not truth.

Comment: I have added `PBYTE dataRead = (BYTE*)malloc(bytesToRead);` and printing `wprintf(L"%s. \n", (WCHAR*)dataRead);` but I am receiving something like this: **???????**.

Comment: @SergioCalderon : a) Does the file contain the null termination that `wprintf` needs; b) what is *actually* in the file?  Is it WCHAR characters, or simple ASCII?  (I would say "dump it with `od -c`, but as you are on Windows, unless you have cygwin, you won't have `od`)

Comment: I wasn't saving the file as UNICODE, thanks for that.